# Setting a DateTime appointment schedule

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-phone

Newbie question about using the DateTime method to set a schedule inside a Telerik calendar. I want to use the Telerik controls calendar to set a schedule for a music bands tour schedule.

I can't seem to get the desired results. Below is the code in my SampleAppointmentSource CS file. I thought that by setting the DateTime.Parse("5/19/2013") that then in all of the appointments when I use the AddDays(1) or AddDays(20) the appointemnts would follow the DateTime.Parse("5/19/2013") pattern but it doesn't. The appointments always use the current date and time (Now). When I add the days, the appointments aren't added to the Parsed date ("5/19/2013"), they are added to the current DateTime. Like the appointments are always referenced to the current system date.

I hope that wasn't to confusing....

What do I need to use to get the desired results?

Is it because of the DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) line? Should it not be DateTime.Now?

```
{
public class SampleAppointmentSource : AppointmentSource
{
    public SampleAppointmentSource()
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        date = DateTime.Parse("5/19/2013");
    }

    public override void FetchData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        this.AllAppointments.Clear();

        this.AllAppointments.Add(new SampleAppointment()
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            Subject = "Jackson W/Warren Hayes",
            AdditionalInfo = "Fain Feild",
            Location = "LoserVille,Kentucky",
        });
```

Comment: Not going to solve the problem you're having, but more a matter of semantics: you have a method called `FetchData` that doesn't return anything, and is instead used for setting data.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I thought, accourding to the Telerik Controls documentation, that the FetchData is used just so the schedule will point to the appointments listed below the FetchData(DateTime) stuff.

This might be my problem though.

Maybe I don't understand the DateTIme well enough. The way I want the code for the appointments to work is to just show the tour schedule. But no matter what AddDays() number I add, it always add the days to the current time. Even launching the app on different days. It always adds to the current date. So the appointment moves so that it reflects adding (1) day to current day.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  If it's required by Telerik, then its their strange method name, not yours :)

Comment: will Windows Phone natively draw a calendar in side the app that I'm building?? Not using the Phone's calendar, just draw a calendar the resides inside the app. I haven't researched this, but I will.

I was just using Telerik because I saw it in a demonstration.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've added further tags to your post so that it might catch the attention of people with more knowledge of Windows Phone and Telerik than I have.

Comment: DateTime.Now will always be the Current DateTime. you should be using your `date` DateTime Object that you create in your constructor, you will need to give it class level scope though.

Comment: Are you using the parameters you're passing `startDate` and `endDate` ? I'm not sure this is your whole method ?

Answer (score 1):

Fleshing out my comment to your question. You create a `DateTime` object called `date` and never use it. DateTime.Now will always return an object containing the current `DateTime`. You need give your `date` DateTime object module Level scope so you can access it in your `FetchData` method. See if something like this works for your.

```
public class SampleAppointmentSource : AppointmentSource
{
    DateTime date;
    public SampleAppointmentSource()
    {
        date = DateTime.Parse("5/19/2013");
     }

    public override void FetchData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        this.AllAppointments.Clear();

        this.AllAppointments.Add(new SampleAppointment()
        {
            StartDate = date.AddDays(1),
            EndDate = date.AddDays(1),
            Subject = "Jackson W/Warren Hayes",
            AdditionalInfo = "Fain Feild",
            Location = "LoserVille,Kentucky",
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying your adjustments Mark, the appointment doesn't show up at all. Under Public Class - The DateTime date; - date has a green line under it. When I hold the mouse over it, I get a message from VS = SampleAppointmentSource.date is never assigned to, and will always have its default value.

It's represented as a warning and not an error. Almost like it is just being ignored. Adding the 'Now' to the StartDate = DateTime.AddDays(1), doesn't change anything either.

I really do appreciate al your help.

Comment: Sorry, after commenting out the DateTime date = new DateTime();

The warning goes away, but the appointment is still ignored.